# Gulp Task ReferenceError: requite is not defined -

Tags: javascript, gulp, netsuite

I'm trying to setup VSCODE to upload scripts to NetSuite. I'm using this video as guide https://youtu.be/Q9wrP5GrFTU .

And my Gulp file is defined as this:

```
requite('./node_modules/@hitc/netsuite-tools/gulptools')
.setupHITCGulp(require('gulp'));
```

But when I'm pressing my keyboard shortcut, the following error occured:

```
> Executing task: gulp build-and-upload --file /eklon/NetSuite/Venturus/Studies/gulpfile.js <

ReferenceError: requite is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/eklon/NetSuite/Venturus/Studies/gulpfile.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at requireOrImport (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js:19:11)
    at execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js:37:3)
The terminal process "gulp 'build-and-upload', '--file', '/eklon/NetSuite/Venturus/Studies/gulpfile.js'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require('./node_modules/@hitc/netsuite-tools/gulptools')
.setupHITCGulp(require('gulp'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change `requite` to `require`.

Answer (score 1):

`requite` is not a keyword you should use `require`

Answer (score 0):

The require function is intended to add separate pieces of code (“modules”) to the current scope, a feature that was not part of the JavaScript/ECMAScript language until the ES2015 specification.

Therefore this function is not specific to ReactJS, and is not part of the language either, which is why Firefox throws an error when you attempt to use it in a vanilla browser environment.

Using require to load modules synchronously is generally part of a method known as CommonJS (see this answer for more on module formats). While an environment such as Node.js provides a module API similar to this specification, browsers do not; so you must bring the function yourself.

There are many options to do so, and it is up to you to pick the one that best suits your workflow and personal taste. But overall, the patterns come down to either:

Explicitly use a module loader in the browser: using a  tag, bring a loader such as SystemJS and immediately use it to load your own code.
Bundle your code to a single script: using a bundler such as Browserify, Webpack, or JSPM, and load the results using a single  tag. The bundler brings along its own module loader.